# Find missing data in consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, dolphindb

Table has an index , it starts from 1 and the rest will be sequentially numbered, and now there are missing data that cause discoontinuity, how can I write sql to find the serial number missing, such as the following, by serial number sorting line number is greater than the ratio of the current line number 1 data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deltas](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/d/deltas.html) function, for example:

```py
t=table(1..10 join [12, 14,16] as id)  
select id from t where deltas(id)>1
```

The id in the above t table jumps from 10 to 12, 14, 16, and the select statement can query 12, 14, and 16.